# SATA 6Gb/s drive only works in legacy mode (SATA 3Gb/s)

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I've got ASUS Sabertooth 990FX mobo (rev. 1.0) with AMD SB950 controller for SATAIII drives and JMicron JMB362 for SATAII drives.

I've got Intel 330 SSD hooked up to SATAIII (AMD) controller and it works perfectly, however, when I try to connect my Seagate SATA 6Gb/s drive (ST1500DL003-9VT16L) to AMD controller it never gets recognized in BIOS, like it's not there at all, no errors, nothing, even though I can hear the drive spinning up.

Currently I'm using this drive in legacy mode (with JMicron controller) and it works perfectly, apart from being slowed down due to the slower interface.

What could possibly cause this? Unfortunately, I don't have any spare SATA3 mobo to test this same drive, but the controller seems absolutely fine, SSD works great and HDD still doesn't work even if I hook it up in the same port used for SSD.

This drive has the latest (and the only one available) firmware (CC32), I tested it with SeaTools and it passes all basic tests.

What could be the culprit? My best guess is that the drive controller itself treats interfaces differently using different pcb components, some of which are faulty, but it seems like a longshot.

Comment: Have you tried a different SATA cable?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention, tried half a dozen of cables, it didn't matter.

Comment: Is there perhaps a BIOS update available for your motherboard?

Comment: No, I'm afraid, I've got the latest BIOS version.

Answer (score 0):

- 

I know this is an old thread, but for the record:

Two of the ports, per the manual, the top black ones I believe, are SATA II only. So no SATA III speeds on those ports. This is also complicated by the fact that the lower two white ports (the real Jmicron ports?), are labeled SATA 1 and 2 on the board, and we also see SATA 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 above the black ports. For more even more confusion, the manual shows and says that the top two black ports, are the SATA II ports. The only way to know is to do a SSD speed test and see which one wins! (I'm not able to do that just now).

Hope that helps.

Regards . . .